# VBA need to find row number until specific value on multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, match

I'm pretty new to VBA and I want to do a macro that will apply "Autofilter" on all my active worksheets. My problems is that the range where the autofilter needs to be applied varies on all worksheets. The autofilter needs to be applied on all worksheets on the 1st row where the value "Transactions" appears.

So far, I've manage to apply the autofilter on all worksheets but it only calculates the match on the active worksheed and apply it to all the other. I would need it to recalculate it for all worksheet.

Thanks in advance!

Sub AutoFilter()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Facturation" Then
        lRow = WorksheetFunction.Match("Transactions", Range("A:A"), 0)
    ws.Range("A" & lRow & ":M" & lRow).AutoFilter

    End If
Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: Qualify the range of the match: `ws.Range("A:A")` ??

Comment: It worked! Thanks!